# ASCII Text to ASCII Number converter with apperance frequency and asterisks in python

Tags: python, list, ascii, percentage

I am new in the field of programming and I need your help with an issue I am facing. I am creating a Python program which takes an ASCII text as input, converts its characters in to ASCII number values, then removes the even numbers & finally displays the frequency of repeatance of the remaining into percentage and asterisks(*). One asterisk is represented as 1% (i.e. 5% = 5 asterisks).

I am having problem in displaying the asterisks values. Below you can see the results I am taking from VS code.

```
f = open(r"c:\python\7_ASCII\Sample.txt", "r")
my_text = f.read()
ascii = []
for word in my_text:
    ascii_word = []
    for char in word:
        ascii_word.append(ord(char))
    ascii.append(ascii_word)
print('Λίστα Δύο Διαστάσεων:',ascii)

flatten_ascii = [val for sublist in ascii for val in sublist]
print('Λίστα Μίας Διάστασης:',flatten_ascii,)

def remove_even(flatten_ascii):
    odd_list = []
    for i in flatten_ascii:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            odd_list.append(i)
    return odd_list
print('Λίστα Μονών ASCII:',remove_even(flatten_ascii))

all_freq = {}
for i in (remove_even(flatten_ascii)):
    if i in all_freq:
        all_freq[i] += 1
    else:
        all_freq[i] = 1
print(str(all_freq))

count = Counter(remove_even(flatten_ascii)).items()

percentages = {x: int(float(y) / len(remove_even(flatten_ascii)) * 100) for x,y in count}

for name, pct in percentages.items():
        print('%s - %s%s' % (name, pct, '%'))
```

And this is the output I am getting (I am giving you only the percentage output, to avoid confusion)

```
{121: 1, 111: 3, 105: 4, 115: 2, 97: 6, 101: 9, 103: 6, 45: 2, 117: 2, 109: 2}
121 - 2%
111 - 8%
105 - 10%
115 - 5%
97 - 16%
101 - 24%
103 - 16%
45 - 5%
117 - 5%
109 - 5%
```

Any ideas on how to display the following output?

```
121 - ** 2% 
111 - ******** 8%
105 - ********** 10%
115 - ***** 5%
97 - **************** 16%
101 - ************************ 24%
103 - **************** 16%
45 - ***** 5%
117 - ***** 5%
109 - ***** 5%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

```py
5*'*' == *****
```

Why not use it like this:

```py
print('{} - {} {}%'.format(name,'*'*pct,pct))
#or
print('%s - %s %s%s' % (name,pct*'*',pct,'%'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, I've tried to solve this for hours. Sorry this is my first question and I can't upvote you. BTW, since I am new in Python what does 5*'*' means??? Any documentation to search for it?

Comment: String multiplication